# lambda expression c# passing two parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an `userTbl` which has columns `UserId` and `UserDriverLicences`. .NET Core routing will wrap the method `GetUserById(id)` : `Id` can be `UserId` or `UserDriverLicences`.

Url:

```
localhost:5000/api/user/id
```

can use `UserId` or `UserDriverLicense` to GET user details.

I have created this method:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)  
{
    return this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>()
        .Where(expression)
        .AsNoTracking();
}
```

So, I'm able to get by `UserId` or `UserDriverLicense` by doing this, but can't be both with same code because I need to map `userId.equals(id)` which is passing to `getUserbyID`

```
public UserTbl GetUserById(int id) 
{
    return FindByCondition(user=> user.UserId.Equals(id))
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new UserTbl()) 
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I think it's a matter of how to pass multiple parameters in lambda ex. But not sure at all.

I expected `GetUserById` can pass an ID which can be `UserId` or `UserDriverLicense`.

Comment: Have you tried us or eg ||

Comment: Hey @Alex, What's us or eg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
FindByCondition(user=> user.UserId.Equals(id) || user.UserDriverLicense.Equals(id))
```

Comment: is it possible if I combine userid and DLNumber into one int/string then search by this new number? For example, Userid is 1234, DL number is 5678. Then the ID parameter passing into FindUserById(int id = 56784321) ?

Comment: maybe `user=> "" + user.UserDriverLicense + user.UserId == id`